# MySQL query to list common values between 2 users

Tags: mysql

This table lists events and users that are attending the event :

**User         Event**
 Joe            Movie
 Joe            Mall
 Jill              Mall
 Joe            Drinking
 Jenn          Drinking
 Jill              Drinking

How can I run a query on this table to list all the events that are common between 2 given users.

My guess is, this will need a self join, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you post an example of your expected results?

Comment: Also, are you really just looking for a comparison of 2 users or are you looking for all events `Joe` has in common with **anyone**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable joe
JOIN myTable jill ON jill.User='Jill' AND jill.Event=joe.Event
WHERE joe.User='Joe'
```

This might work also. It can sometimes be more efficient doing it this way (putting all conditions in the JOIN)

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable joe
JOIN myTable jill ON jill.User='Jill'
    AND jill.Event=joe.Event
    AND joe.User='Joe'
```

Comment: Finnally used, 'SELECT joe.event FROM events as joe JOIN events as jill ON jill.user='Jill' AND jill.event=joe.event WHERE joe.user="Joe"' -- Both 'AND' & 'WHERE' work.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
   FROM myTable t1
      JOIN myTable t2 
         ON t1.event = t2.event
       and t2.User="Jill"
   where
      t1.user = "Joe"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select event from table group by event having count(user) =2
```

that won't give you the names of the users though

Answer (score 0):

```
select eventname from user_event JOIN user_event as t2 USING (eventname) 
where user_event.username="joe" and t2.username="jill"
```

Here, 'user_event' is the name of your table and table 't2' is the alias of the 'user_event" table